# How to use onButtonClick(self) to update a wx.ComboBox

Tags: python-2.7, combobox, wxpython

I'm using the code below to populate a combo box. However, when I run my application, it detects all media files in the designated path ... and if I happen to add another file while the app is running and attempt to click the drop down button for the combo box, the list of items in the combobox is not updated with the recently added item/s, therein lies the problem:

```
...
...
...
#Select Media path
os.chdir("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin")
wrkdir = os.getcwd()
filelist = os.listdir(wrkdir)
self.formats1 = []

for filename in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(filename)
    if filename.endswith(".avi") or filename.endswith(".mp4") or filename.endswith(".flv") or filename.endswith(".mov") or filename.endswith(".mpeg4") or filename.endswith(".mpeg") or filename.endswith(".mpg2") or filename.endswith(".mkv") or filename.endswith(".m4v") or filename.endswith(".wav") or filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            self.formats1.append(filename)

self.format_combo1=wx.ComboBox(panel, size=(140, -1),value='Select Media', choices=self.formats1, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN, pos=(300,50))

...
...
....
```

After some reading, I discovered that wx.ComboBox is a subclass of wxControlWithItems, wx.combo.ComboCtrl, and wx.Choice, so it also can use their methods. I found one method (OnButtonClick()) that sounds like it will do what I need it to do - once the drop down arrow is clicked, update the combobox list with the items in the directory. But, there is no description on how to use it. Can someone steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the combox event 'wx.EVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN and set the items you want to appear.

**Note: WxPython Version 2.9.5**

•EVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN(id, func):
Process a wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN event, which is generated when the list box part of the combo box is shown (drops down). Notice that this event is currently only supported by wxMSW and wxGTK with GTK+ 2.10 or later.

```
import wx


class Mainframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.count = 1

        self.combo_box = wx.ComboBox(panel, size=(140, -1),
            value='Select choice', choices=[])
        self.combo_box.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN, self.on_combo_drop)

    def on_combo_drop(self, event):
        self.combo_box.Set(['Item{}'.format(number) for
                            number in xrange(self.count, self.count + 5)])
        self.count += 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Mainframe(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way to catch the event you want. You would probably need to create a custom control or use ComboCtrl instead.

See the following thread for some ideas:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/How-to-capture-mouse-click-on-wx-ComboBox-down-arrow-td2333992.html